# Gulp: How to set dest folder relative to processed file (when using wildcards)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Under my `assets/` folder, I have numerous subfolders, each containing an arbitrary number of images, like so:

```
assets/article1/
assets/article2/
```

I'm trying to write a gulp task to locate all `.jpg` images within and generate their thumbnail versions, to be saved in a `thumbs/` subfolder within the folder where each file resides:

```
assets/article1/               # original jpg images
assets/article1/thumbs/        # thumbnail versions of above..
assets/article2/
assets/article2/thumbs/
```

I've been trying various approaches but no luck. The closest I've come is:

```
gulp.task('thumbs', function () {
    return gulp.src( './assets/**/*.jpg' )
        .pipe( imageResize( { width: 200 } ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( function( file ) { return file.base + '/thumbs/'; } ) );
});
```

However, this creates a single `thumbs\` folder at the root of `assets\`

```
assets/article1/
assets/article2/
assets/thumbs/article1/
assets/thumbs/article2/
```

Is there a good info on the paths and wildcards anywhere? Clearly I'm not handling it well..

Answer (score 7):

You could use `path.dirname` for that: http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p

```
// require core module
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('thumbs', function () {
    return gulp.src( './assets/**/*.jpg' )
        .pipe( imageResize( { width: 200 } ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( function( file ) { return path.join(path.dirname(file.path), 'thumbs'); } ) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Closer, I suppose, but not quite there. Produces: `assets/article1/thumbs/article1/`  Will dig into `path' more..

Comment: this is a bit tricky because of your recursive glob using '**/*.js'. Maybe take a look at this official recipe: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md

Comment: I think I'm getting what they're doing - create a list of folders, then run a task on each folder separately. Having burnt half a day on it, I just ended up changing the app to look for the thumbs folder at the root of assets ;) But I appreciate the help, good to know for next time!

Comment: change the base path in gulp.src `return gulp.src( './assets/**/*.jpg' , {base : '.'})`. this should give you path starting from '.' and not './assets/'.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me given the following directory structure (I simplified a bit to focus on just getting the files in the right place)

```
assets/article1/1.jpg
assets/article2/2.jpg
```

with a desired outcome of

```
assets/article1/1.jpg
assets/article1/thumbs/1.jpg
assets/article2/2.jpg
assets/article2/thumbs/2.jpg
```

Here's what worked for me (modified from this recipe https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md)

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');

var scriptsPath = 'assets'; // folder to process

function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
      .filter(function(file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
      });
}

gulp.task('thumbs', function() {
   var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);

   return folders.map(function(folder) {
      return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, folder, '/**/*.jpg'))
        .pipe(rename({dirname: folder + '/thumbs/'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath));
   });
});
```

Comment: I dont feel like that is a good way to deal with it. Could you elaborate your solution? My main issue is that gulp.src() gives you a vinyl-stream and a vinyl-stream is needed in gulp.task as return value. What you are doing is returning an array of vinyl-streams. As of the current stable version of Gulp.js (3.9.x) I guess this could lead to horrible side-effects. Take a look at this issue here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/95 - Solution: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md

Answer (score 0):

I've found another approach that may be useful for anyone searching this post.
My original goal was very similar to your request, and this approach may be adjusted to almost any particular need.

```
function scss(cb) {
src('./*/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename({extname: '.min.css'}))
    .pipe(tap(function(file) {
      //Enrich the file with crucial information about it's original path, you can save anything you may need. In my case filename is quite enough. It's important to move this block before any sourcemap write if you've any.
      file.name = path.basename(file.path);
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(flatten()) //Remove file relative paths.
    .pipe(dest(
      function( file ) {
        //Reconstruct final path using insight we saved before, and using a clean base path provided by flatten.
        return path.join(path.dirname(file.path), file.name.replace(/\.min\..+$/, ''), 'static');
      }));
cb();
```

}